# Search in Unity is very slow?

Tags: unity, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Dash only show installed applications by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219743/how-do-i-make-dash-only-show-installed-applications-by-default)

Am I able to turn off some search scope?

eg: turn off suggest.

Basically I want to search application only, so it should be super fast.

Comment: Assuming OP wants to find only installed applications, this question would be a duplicate of [How do I make Dash only show installed applications by default?](http://askubuntu.com/q/219743/25656).

Comment: I don't think it's the same topic